# How to serve a PDF which is fetched from a third-party API in Python/Django?

Tags: python, django, pdf

I'm fetching a PDF from a third-party API and I'm getting the file contents as string back from the API. I'm trying to serve it in the browser but the file is blank for some reason. It shouldn't be. Below is my code:

```
# This returns the pdf bytes as string
document = get_document()

response = HttpResponse(document, content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename=some_file.pdf'
return response
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should set the content disposition header as an attachment.

Response header should contain:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="some_file.pdf"
```

Python equivalent:

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="some_file.pdf"'
```

### Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment

Comment: I will try that but I do think "inline" should work, no?